# What's the difference between check synchronously and asynchronously in check?

Tags: node.js

What's the difference between check existing file synchronously and asynchronously in node.js?

For example:

```
var path = require('path');
if (path.existsSync("/the/path")) { // or fs.existsSync
    // ...
}
```

and

```
// Is it a directory?
lstat('/the/path', function(err, stats) {
    if (!err && stats.isDirectory()) {
        // Yes it is
    }
});
```

Comment: The difference is that one is asynchronous (does not wait) and one is synchronous (blocking, waits for the file I/O to finish).

Comment: The synchronous methods shouldn't be used never never never!! or you'll be loosing all the node.js platform benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronous versions of the `fs` method provide their results via the method's return value; as a result these methods have to block while the I/O is performed to determine the result.

The asynchronous versions provide their results via the method's callback function that the caller provides as a parameter to the method.  The methods just initiate the required I/O and then return immediately, so the return value from these methods isn't useful.  When the I/O later completes, the callback is invoked to provide the result back to the caller.